# Character array Assignment

Tags: c

```
int main()
{ 
     char s[]="stack";
     s="overflow";
}
```

This is not allowed.Its gives an error.But below code works fine.

```
int main()
{
      char s[]="stack";
      strcpy(s,"overflow");
}
```

Why this happens?

Comment: can anybody explain why this happens based on memory allocation???

Comment: See the definition of `strcpy`

Comment: When you say that the lower segment "works" you mean the compiler does not throw an error, or s appears to contain "overflow"?

Comment: For the second program, you should initialize `s` to `"buffer"` to more accurately describe what is happening.

Comment: Also note that in the second case, you're going off the end of the array, so you're invoking UB.

Answer (score -1):

The variable `s` represents a pointer to the string. More specifically, it refers to the memory address of the first letter in your string `"stack"`. Due to this reason, the operation `s="overflow"` makes no sense. How can you set the value of s (a pointer) to a string?

Keep in mind that C is a very low-level language, so you have to be wary of things that might seem intuitive to you not behaving the way you expect them to.

Comment: It doesn't decay into a pointer. It's a character array and you can't change the base address of an array once allocated.

Comment: You can't change it, but you can treat it like a pointer in some cases (such as for pointer arithmetic: `s + 1` refers to the second character in the array).

Comment: Yes, true indeed. But your `How can you set the value of s (a pointer) to a string?` statement is misleading.